# How to encrypt params sent through a request to my server?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, https, httprequest

I send HTTPS requests to a Node JS server. I use URLSession in Swift and I'd like to encrypt the data I send so they can't be read.

Here is my code for now:

```
let boundary=generate_boundary_string()
var request=URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod="POST"
request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary"+boundary, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")

//prepare body with params
let body=NSMutableData()
for (key, value) in params{
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
}
request.httpBody=body

//send the request
let session=URLSession.shared
let task=session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
    guard data != nil else{return}

    //decode received data
    //...
}).resume()
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: https is already encrypted, the data cannot be read by a third party. As long as your certificate chain is not broken. Make sure the https certificate is validated and if you are concerned about that data make sure that certificate pinning is activated as well.

Comment: I need to obfuscate some of my parameters so they can't be read in case of "man in the middle" attack. (By the way, my ssl certificate is valid, I don't have any problem on that side).

Comment: If you use certificate pinning there is no mitm attack. Regarding the certificate I was refering to making sure your app does under no circumstances turn of ssl validation, allowing untrusted certificates.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the certificate pinning, I'll look into it. With this activated, someone using Charles proxy or Burp Suite won't be able to see the data?

Comment: (Right now, I can read the data with these programs, it's not encrypted)

Comment: HTTPS encrypts everything except the address portion of the URL, you will do no better. If you add certificate pinning, that is verifying that the certificate belongs to the server you want to connect to MITM attacks will not be possible.